# I want my iframe/embed/object tag to use localstorage html as the src

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have html stored as some value in local storage

```
key               value
someHTML         <html>code</html>
```

I want either an embed/iframe/object tag to display that value as its source

```
<embed src="localStorage value">
```

You may have questions such as "Why don't you just ...."  But I have reasons for needing to do it this way.  I only have access to local storage and not able to run things server side. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the data as a string from localstorage and use the srcdoc attribute for an iframe

```
<iframe srcdoc="<html><body></body></html>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Works surprisingly well: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5xz42ase/

Comment: thank you.  I didn't realize that was what srcdoc was for but my next question/hope.....Can I use srcdoc with embed and object tags as well?

Comment: @JoshuaRobison no, you can't, those two elements do not support that attribute. Maybe a _Data URI_ could work though.

Comment: thank you.  I switched my page to use iframes and it works awesome!  It was a great solution for making mini thumbnails of the content of my localstorage items.